# PageView "jumps" when dragged

Tags: dart, flutter

Has somebody noticed this?

I have a PageView, and when I drag it to slide to the next page, it first doesn't move, and then after I drag a bit more, the slide suddenly "jumps", as if the distance dragged all happen instantly.

I also run the app in release and profile mode, but it's always the same behaviour. Also the amount of subviews per page doesn't seem to affect it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'TipField.dart';
import '../data/TipFieldData.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ticket/theme.dart';

class Ticket extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _TicketState createState() => _TicketState();
}


class _TicketState extends State<Ticket> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 400.0,
      height:400.0,
      child: PageView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return TipField(
                  index,
                  7,
                  TipFieldData(1, 6),
                  AppColors.redLight,
                  AppColors.redLightest,
                  AppColors.red
                );
              },
            itemCount: 12,
          )
    );
    
  }

}
```